# How to center a child element in CSS, even if it is larger than the parent?

Tags: html, css

I would like to create a css class so a div can be placed in the center of its parent. The code I am using is:

```
.centered {
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;

    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}
```

It works if the parent is larger than the child element, or has the same size: 
https://jsfiddle.net/cy8dn1km/

But if the child is larger, then its center is not positioned at the center of its parent. Instead their left borders will be at the same place, and the child element will be extended only to right:

https://jsfiddle.net/797L7nce/

Something is wrong with the horizontal centering.

How is it possible to fix it using CSS only (**without using CSS 2D/3D transformations**), without adding new container elements?

Comment: I'm curious if there will be any clever answers to this one. Afraid you're out of luck though.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here is a solution without using CSS 2D/3D transformations. You can use `display: flex` with `flex-direction: column` (this is **important**) on parent element and `display: table` on child element.

```css
body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: green;
}
.centered.d1 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.d1 {
  background: yellow;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
.d2 {
  background: red;
  opacity: 0.7;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  display: table;
}
```

```html
<div class="centered d1">
  <div class="centered d2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Paulie_D Yea its weird `:)`, also `flex-direction: column` is for chrome but on firefox it works with `row`.

Comment: Add the [Bootstrap 4](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/flexbox/#justify-content) classes `.d-flex.justify-content-center` to the container to center horizontally. They don't appear to work when the child is larger in both the _x_ and _y_ directions.

Comment: You saved my ass. +1

Answer (score 24):

Add `left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, 0);`and remove `right: 0px;`

```
.centered {
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    bottom: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/797L7nce/4/)

Comment: I dont like translate() that much in CSS, but for this problem it seems like the best solution, even if it is a 2D CSS transformation

Answer (score 5):

If you know the dimentions of the elements you can use the left/top position at 50% with negative margins of half the element size.

I have updated your fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/797L7nce/2/

```
.centered {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;

}

.d1 {
    background: yellow;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-left:-25px;
    margin-top:-25px;
}

.d2 {
    background: red;
    opacity: 0.7;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    margin-left:-125px;
    margin-top:-125px;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Ok i tried **without 2D CSS** :

Change `absolute`to `fixed` and add some `margin: auto;`

[JSfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/797L7nce/8/)

```css
body, html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    position: relative;
    background: green;
}

.centered {
    position: fixed;
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}

.d1 {
    background: yellow;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}

.d2 {
    background: red;
    opacity: 0.7;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="centered d1">
    <div class="centered d2">

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @IterAtor This is the reason why I suggested changing the position from absolute to fixed in my very first sentence.

Answer (score 3):

You're almost there. Just set the absolute positions to the same (large) negative number, to make enough room for the `auto` margin:

```
.centered {
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;

    bottom: -9999px;
    left: -9999px;
    top: -9999px;
    right: -9999px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/797L7nce/9/

Comment: `inset: -9999px;` is shorthand for setting `bottom`, `left`, `top`, and `right` all at once

Answer (score 2):

Adding the below **CSS** to `.d2` will solve the issue.

```
.d2 {
    background: red;
    opacity: 0.7;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-125px;
}
```

You can check the demo **[here](https://jsfiddle.net/797L7nce/3/)**

Answer (score 1):

In **[Bootstrap 4](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/)**:

to ***center the child horizontally***, use bootstrap-4 class:

```
justify-content-center
```

to ***center the child vertically***, use bootstrap-4 class:

```
 align-items-center
```

but remember don't forget to use ***d-flex*** class with these
it's a bootstrap-4 utility class, like so

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" style="height:100px;">
    <span class="bg-primary">MIDDLE</span>    
</div>
```

**Note:** make sure to add bootstrap-4 utilities if this code does not work

I know it's not the direct answer to this question but it may help someone

Answer (score 0):

A simple technique is to use flex and set the child to have shrink 0.

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.child {
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

Source with other examples:
https://mastery.games/post/how-to-pin-element-to-center-of-parent/